# How to update Object in Array dynamically in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I'm fairly new to ReactJS and wrote this function I want to use to update an object in my state. It seems unable to use the "name" param to update my object and I don't really get why. I tried to code it in template literals as well.

```
const handleAccountingChange = (newValue, name, id) => {
  const newState = selected.map((obj) => {
    if (obj.id === id) {
      return { ...obj, name: newValue };
    }
    return obj;
  });
  setSelected(newState);
};
```

I get no error in the browser console, but it doesn't update my state either. Any idea would be appreciated. I spent 2 hours on google but didn't find anything.

Comment: Do you want the object to have the `name` field literally, or do you want the object have the field of whatever `name`'s value is in the function?

Comment: Try putting debugger inside function and check if the `newState` is different from the `selected` value when the `setSelected` is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `obj.property = 'aaa'` you set `property` to `aaa`.
What you try to do is update the property contained by the variable `name`, what you code does is update the property `name`.

To update a property from a variable you need to use :

```
const property = 'name'
obj[property] = 'aaa'
```

equivalente to :

```
obj.name == 'aaa'
```

This code solves your probleme :

```js
const handleAccountingChange = (newValue, name, id) => {
    // For the exemple I declare selected here
    const selected = [ {id: 1, test: 'aaa'}, {id: 2, test: 'bbb'} ];
    
    const newState = selected.map((obj) => {
        if (obj.id === id) {
            let myObj = {...obj};
            myObj[name] = newValue;
            return myObj;
        }
        return obj;
    });

    return newState; // instead ou can use setSelected(newState)
};



console.log(handleAccountingChange('ccc', 'test', 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleAccountingChange = (newValue, name, id) => {
const newState = selected.map((obj) => {
if (obj.id === id) {
return { obj[name]= newValue};
}
return obj;
});
setSelected({...newState});
}
```

Comment: Hey sohan! Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for the answer. A good answer shouldn't be code-only but also include an explanation. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer